# jQuery Ajax call to F#?

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services, f#

Is there any way to make a call to an f# library using jQuery without having to wrap it into a web service method?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining an alternative, short of writing an FSharp compiler or IL decompiler that produces JavaScript as its target language. What exactly are you looking for? What's the problem that makes you resist exposing your functionality as a service?

Comment: You could write your own http server, basically open port 80 and react to the appropriate commands.

Comment: @Jason, this is strictly a theoretical test project I am trying to work out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you could translate F# to JavaScript. This is actually pretty doable, because it can use quotations (a high-level representation of F# code). There are two projects that do this. One is a rather sophisticated [commercial project named WebSharper](http://www.intellifactory.com/products/wsp/Home.aspx) (which has other features too) and the other one is [open source project FSharp.Javascript](http://fscript.justsimplecode.com/).

If you want to avoid web services, you can also write a simple HTTP server. This would be a standalone application that you can run on your server and it will directly handle requests. I did that using `HttpListener` class in a recent [talk in London](http://tomasp.net/blog/education-and-agents-talks.aspx). You can [find the sample here](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Talks%202010/Agents%20%28London%29/Demos/Demo.ChatServer/Server.fsx).

There are definitely other ways - if you're working in ASP.NET application, then you can use `HttpHandler` or a page written in F# that will just handle the request directly. It is probably easier to have the main front-end as a C# project, but you can write the page/handler in F# and just reference it or inherit from it in C# (example [using ASP.NET MVC is here](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-mvc-web.aspx)).

Comment: +1: my company uses ASP.NET MVC + jquery for exactly this purpose: jQuery makes an Ajax call to a controller method, the method returns a JsonResult, jQuery can extract it out and show it on screen. We use C# in the backend, but there's no reason in principle why you couldn't use F#.

Comment: The FSharp.Javascript project has improved pretty drastically in recent months and I'd love to hear some feedback on it.  I also created the FSharp.Javascript.Mvc (https://github.com/jgreene/FSharp.Javascript.Mvc) project for use with the ASP.NET MVC framework.  As an example I wrote Tetris in F# and it runs in the browser here: http://fscript.justsimplecode.com/canvas

Comment: @Thank you for the comprehensive answer and the useful links!

Comment: @justin I'm quite interested in the project - I just need to find an excuse to use it for something :-)!

Comment: @Juliet, the company I work for does the same thing with Grails + jQuery ("webservices" are just controller actions which process either URL encoded GETs or JSON encoded POSTs and respond with JSON encoded plain text) to great effect both for Swing clients and browser clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a HttpHandler as a wrapper.