# F# JQuery Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, f#

I'm trying to make an `Ajax Post` to my `F# controller` so I can call a method, that will print and simple string. Eventually instead of string being displayed, information selected via a checkbox on the webpage will be inserted into a database.

I have been trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414942/jquery-ajax-call-to-f) to help but I don't really understand it.

My JQuery code at the momment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Add').click(function () {
        var id = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
            id[i] = $(this).val();
        });

        if (id.length === 0) {
            alert("Please select at least one checkbox")
        }
        else {
            $.post('http://localhost:48214/api/table/?InsertData');
        }
        console.log();
    })
});
```

My `controller` looks like this:

```ml
member this.PostInsertData (Insert : string) =  
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called method insert data into table")
        Table.insertDataTest
        //http://localhost:48214/api/table/?InsertData
        //^Link to post request
```

My `insertDataTest` method:

```ml
let insertDataTest  =
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Method Called!")
```

I know through the windows postman application that the a post is possible, as I've had the strings appear in my output.
I'm just wondering why a post request will work through postman but not through my web api?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the controller and the method

Controller:

```
member this.PostInsertData (Insert : string) =  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called method insert data into table")
    Table.insertDataTest()
    //http://localhost:48214/api/table/?InsertData
    //^Link to post request
```

My insertDataTest method:

```
let insertDataTest() =
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Method Called!")
```